# How can I check a query execution?

Tags: eclipse

I am working on a project where I came across on a sql query. I want see the execution flow fully. i.e how the query executed on database. what can I do for this?

can any body help me for this?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Which database are you using? Which tools? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Atomic Operations**
The query will be an atomic operation so that you could set table A.Description = table B.Description without having to worry about overwriting the data from either table.

**A great book on sql querying** -The book that you need to read is Inside Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008: T-SQL Querying. This will show you exactly how a query is processed. You can also use Display Estimated Execution Plan / Show Actual Execution Plan setting in sql server management studio to see a visual plan. You can right click the query pane to toggle them on and off.  You will have to figure out how to read it first.

**Actual Order of query based on Itzak Ben-Gan in the book.**

```
1 FROM
2 ON <join_condition>
3 <join_type> JOIN <right_table>
4 WHERE <where_condition>
5 GROUP BY <group_by_list>
6 WITH { CUBE | ROLEUP }
7 HAVING <having_condition>
8 SELECT 
9 DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY <order_by_list>
11 TOP
```